# Simple Spy Not Cache image

Tags: jquery, caching

Simple spy is very useful jquery plugin/Code! but i see this not cache image and send many request to server! any one know what's problem ?

Spy Code :

```
$(function () {
    $('ul.spy').simpleSpy();
});

(function ($) {

$.fn.simpleSpy = function (limit, interval) {
    limit = limit || 4;
    interval = interval || 4000;

    return this.each(function () {
        // 1. setup
            // capture a cache of all the list items
            // chomp the list down to limit li elements
        var $list = $(this),
            items = [], // uninitialised
            currentItem = limit,
            total = 0, // initialise later on
            height = $list.find('> li:first').height();

        // capture the cache
        $list.find('> li').each(function () {
            items.push('<li>' + $(this).html() + '</li>');
        });

        total = items.length;

        $list.wrap('<div class="spyWrapper" />').parent().css({ height : height * limit });

        $list.find('> li').filter(':gt(' + (limit - 1) + ')').remove();

        // 2. effect        
        function spy() {
            // insert a new item with opacity and height of zero
            var $insert = $(items[currentItem]).css({
                height : 0,
                opacity : 0
            }).prependTo($list);
            // fade the LAST item out
            $list.find('> li:last').animate({ opacity : 0}, 1000, function () {
                // increase the height of the NEW first item
                $insert.animate({ height : height }, 1000).animate({ opacity : 1 }, 1000);

                // AND at the same time - decrease the height of the LAST item
                // $(this).animate({ height : 0 }, 1000, function () {
                    // finally fade the first item in (and we can remove the last)
                    $(this).remove();
                // });
            });

            currentItem++;
            if (currentItem >= total) {
                currentItem = 0;
            }

            setTimeout(spy, interval)
        }

        spy();
    });
};

})(jQuery);
```

Orginal Source : http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/simple-spy.html
Demo Ib JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/treeface/xaJ9F/ 
Picture of firebug : ...

XXXXX CHRISTMAS XXXXX

Comment: [link](http://ctrlv.in/54802) Firebug Image

Comment: I've just checked. And it actually caches them

Comment: after check please wait a moment! u see. see fire bug image

Comment: Yeah, I'll see it now. It's because there's no image preloading in this script

Comment: In your opinion, how should it be ?!

Answer (score 0):

Just add image preloading to the script.
You can find good examples of how to do it here: [Preloading images with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery)

Comment: Yeah! This is the perfect solution, but exactly where and how